# Stuck at table function

Tags: sql, database, count, table-functions

```
Dept_No (Int)
Dept_Name (Char(30))
```

and using the following database:

```
EMPLOYEE (fmane, minit, lname, ssn, birthdate, address, sex, salary, superssn, dno)     KEY: ssn
DEPARTMENT (dname, dnumber, mgrssn, mgrstartdate)               KEY: dnumber.
PROJECT  (pname, pnumber, plocation, dnum)                          KEY: pnumber.
```

I'm stuck at right now, want give me some advice on starting it? really don't know where to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select e.Dept_No, d.Dept_Name, Count(e.Dept_No), 
SUM(e.salary) as Sum_Salary,
AVG(e.salary)  as AVE_Salary
from EMPLOYEE e
join DEPARTMENT d ON e.dno = d.dnumber
Group by e.Dept_No, d.Dept_Name
```

- First you need to join dept and emp tables.
- Since you need total salary by dept you have to group by dept no
- also you want to show dept_name so you have to group by it as well
- If you have columns except functions(avg,sum.. etc) you have to add
  these columns group by statement.

Comment: also can I email you? I just have one minor question left, too long to post on here

Comment: Sharing e mail here may not be legal so you had better prepare your question's summary with nice explanation.I help if i can.

Comment: okay thanks, are there anyway to contact you? what I mean I was I will post my code here maybe using a new question and see if you can answer. Please consider help me, thank you

Comment: I don't know if any contact way exist. I will be checking your activity to see your question but be sure that there are a lot of people who can help you in so.